# How to call a function in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having difficulty calling the `install_apache` function from the task:

```
task :install_apache => :environment do
  begin
    install_apache
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e
  end
end

def install_apache
  # Code...
end
```

Comment: Are you receiving an error message? If so, could you post that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby, you must first define a method. You do that using the syntax

```
def method_name
  # code goes here
end
```

To call the method, you simply type in the method name

```
method_name
```

In your case, you had the first step down

```
def install_apache
end
```

You need to add another line in your code like so

```
install_apache
```

Comment: Thank yo !! can this method be out side of the task ?

Comment: Yes you can. When Ruby runs through the task block, it will see the method install_apache. It will then search for the install_apache method and then execute that code, before returning to the task block.

Comment: @raviTeja Don't forget to accept the answer, and maybe vote it up.

Comment: @NabilKadimi, I will check the code and I will accept it!!

Comment: Hello DarkMouse,
It's not working for me, may be i was doing wrong on something:
here is what I have tried:

"def install_apache
      begin
         #code
      rescue Exception => e         
         puts e
      end
end

task :install_apache => : environment do
  begin
      install_apache #calling function
  rescue Exception => e
  puts e
"